# How can I combine the ssh and cd commands?

Tags: bash, ssh, git, cd-command

I am trying to write a bash-script to update a remote git repo. 
The script looks something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh user@remote.de 'cd /home/h/usr/praktikum  | git pull | sbatch run.sh'
```

However, the `cd` command has no effect!

> fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /home)

How can I get into the git folder: `/home/h/usr/praktikum` to run my git commands?

Comment: Why are you piping `|` the outputs of the commands into each other? Could it be that you accidentally used `|` instead of `&&`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works to me:

```
ssh user@remote.de -t "cd /home/h/usr/praktikum && git pull && sbatch run.sh; bash --login"
```

For not will leave you in a remote shell:

```
ssh user@remote.de -t "cd /home/h/usr/praktikum && git pull && sbatch run.sh"
```

Answer (score 4):

Pipes (`|`) are used for connecting inputs and outputs of several command together in a pipeline.  The commands run independently and concurrently with each other, apart from when they are waiting for input to appear or for output to be read.  This is why the `cd` does not affect the current directory of the `git`and `sbatch` commands.  You don't want to use a pipeline here.

What you want to do is

```
ssh user@remote.de 'cd /home/h/usr/praktikum && { git pull; sbatch run.sh; }'
```

What this would do is to `cd` to the specified directory, and if that went well (the directory exists and you have permissions to access it), the `git` and `sbatch` commands are run.

In the command above, `sbatch` would run regardless of the exit status of `git pull`.  If you want to avoid running `sbatch` if `git`for some reason fails, use

```
ssh user@remote.de 'cd /home/h/usr/praktikum && git pull && sbatch run.sh'
```